# SQL Server group by who can solve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

need a help with query to sort out this 'simple' task ;)

tbl1

```
Name    TransDate  Credit Debit  
Diaz    01/01/2015  500   200
Diaz    01/05/2015  500   100
Diaz    01/01/2016  500   200
Maya    01/01/2014  500   300
Maya    01/04/2015  500   300
Maya    01/11/2015  500   200
Jane    01/02/2014  500   200
Jane    01/03/2014  500   100
Jane    01/08/2016  500   300
```

Your Query->

Result tbl2:

```
Name (Credit–Debit)/2014 (Credit–Debit)/2015 (Credit–Debit)/2016
Diaz          0              700                   300
Maya        200              500                     0
Jane        700                0                   200
```

Thanks a lot!!
D.

Comment: How many years you have? Only three, or there can be more?

Comment: if it is simple task, why you are not trying it your self

Comment: @qotqn there can be much more..

Comment: @ Imran Ali Khan you obviously missed the quotes in 'simple'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

**Explanation**

1. Extract the year from the date
2. Find Credit - Debit
3. Apply pivot for the sum in years 2014,2015,2016

Data Setup

I used the data type of Credit and Debit as money, you can use int if you want in your case.

```
declare @data table(
    Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    TransDate date not null,
    Credit money not null,
    Debit money not null
)

insert into @data(Name,TransDate,Credit,Debit)
values ( 'Diaz','2015-01-01',500,200),
       ( 'Diaz','2015-05-01',500,100),
       ( 'Diaz','2016-01-01',500,200),
       ( 'Maya','2014-01-01',500,300),
       ( 'Maya','2015-04-01',500,300),
       ( 'Maya','2015-11-01',500,200),
       ( 'Jane','2014-02-01',500,200),
       ( 'Jane','2014-03-01',500,100),
       ( 'Jane','2016-08-01',500,200)
```

Query

```
;with report as(
    select Name,
    [Year] = datepart(year,TransDate),
    [Credit-Debit] = Credit- Debit
    from @data
)
select Name,
       [Credit-Debit/2014]= isnull([2014],0),
       [Credit-Debit/2015]= isnull([2015],0),
       [Credit-Debit/2016]= isnull([2016],0)
from report
pivot (
    sum([Credit-Debit])
    for [Year] in([2014],[2015],[2016]
)) p
```

The result

```
Name    Credit-Debit/2014   Credit-Debit/2015   Credit-Debit/2016
Diaz    0.00    700.00  300.00
Jane    700.00  0.00    300.00
Maya    200.00  500.00  0.00
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just have limited known number of years, One way could be to use `case` and `aggregation`

```
SELECT
  name,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = '2014' THEN credit - debit
  END), 0) AS credit_debit_2014,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = '2015' THEN credit - debit
  END), 0) AS credit_debit_2015,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = '2016' THEN credit - debit
  END), 0) AS credit_debit_2016
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

**Result:**

```
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| name | credit_debit_2014 | credit_debit_2015 | credit_debit_2016 |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Diaz |                 0 |               700 |               300 |
| Jane |               700 |                 0 |               200 |
| Maya |               200 |               500 |                 0 |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/WLXK53790)**

Answer (score 0):

I like to solve these using conditional aggregation.  The following should work even if `credit` or `debit` is `NULL` for a given year:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 2014
                THEN COALESCE(credit, 0) - COALESCE(debit, 0)
                ELSE 0
           END) as credit_debit_2014,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 2015
                THEN COALESCE(credit, 0) - COALESCE(debit, 0)
                ELSE 0
           END) as credit_debit_2015,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 2016
                THEN COALESCE(credit, 0) - COALESCE(debit, 0)
                ELSE 0
           END) as credit_debit_2016
FROM table1
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: I like your solution. Just a question: Coalesce and isnull are interchangeable in this case?

Comment: @Diaz . . . In this case, the are pretty interchangeable.  The two have subtle differences, but those are not relevant here.